# Number of continous functions from set of all rationals to itself

Tags: real-analysis, rational-numbers

Since Rational numbers is countable it is equivalent to Natural numbers. Now the number sequences forming by more than 2 numbers is uncountable..Also here the open sets are singleton sets. So continuity doesn't fails . Hence the number of continous functions from rationals to itself is uncountable.. Is my argument is true?

Comment: Why are continuous functions $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ *equivalent* to continuous functions $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$? With the usual distance in the naturals, any function is continuous, however that's not the case for $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Can we consider the set of continous function from natural numbers to itself as a subset of continous functions from rationals to itself.. Then since the subset is uncountable the actual set is uncountable?

Comment: Yes, we can. Any function $f : \mathbb{N} \to  \mathbb{N}$ can be extended "linearly" to each $[n,n+1] \cap  \mathbb{Q}$. This yields a continuous extension $F :  \mathbb{Q} \to  \mathbb{Q}$ of $f$.